# Bootstrap with jQuery - Screen Resolution issue with Dropdown hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQuery for Bootstrap Menu hOver for time delay on closing menu.

But the issue now is that, when I check the same in less resolution, still getting the hover state. I want to stop the hover state for the dropdown menu on low resolutions...  Eg: 768px. Unluckily I cant change the code much. :(

> **jQuery**

```
/* Time Delay on Main Menu */   
        /* Main Menu */
        $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
          $(this).find('.pulse-dropdown').stop(true, true).delay(0).fadeIn(0);
        }, function() {
          $(this).find('.pulse-dropdown').stop(true, true).delay(300).fadeOut(300);
        });

        /* Sub Menu */
        $('li.dropdown-submenu').hover(function() {
          $(this).find('.pulse-dropdown2').stop(true, true).delay(0).fadeIn(0);
        }, function() {
          $(this).find('.pulse-dropdown2').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the width of the window using jQuery's `width()` function and attach the listen for the `hover` event only if the window is greater than 768px like so:

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    /* Sub Menu */
    $('li.dropdown-submenu').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.pulse-dropdown2').stop(true, true).delay(0).fadeIn(0);
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.pulse-dropdown2').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
    });

}
```